# Unable to pass textbox var counter total to next page

Tags: javascript, php, session

I found this script online this past weekend. However, reading all the options on how to pass the counter total to the next page has not worked. 
I looked at every possible way online and on Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, most times, the script does not end up working.
I have tried to capture it on the next page with `echo $_SESSION['msg'];` or `echo $_SESSION['counter'];`. I have also tried messing with the `$msg` line.
`<?php echo $counter ?>` also does not work as mentioned in several sites including this one. Also echoing `getButtonValue` didn't seem to work either since it is listing each text box, not the total sum.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 2;
    $("#addButton").click(function () {
        if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
        }   

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
            '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
            '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
        counter++;
    });

    $("#removeButton").click(function () {
        if(counter==1){
            alert("No more textbox to remove");
            return false;
        }   
        counter--;
        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
    });

    $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {
        var msg = '';
        for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
            msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
        }
        alert(msg);
    });
});

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
        <label>Textbox #1 : </label>
        <input type='text' id='textbox1' >
    </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
<input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>
```

Comment: Java **IS NOT** JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, that was how the script came. I forget to mention that I want to capture the total count for one MySQL table, and the textbox data into another table in case anyone was wondering. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One method of passing a JavaScript variable from one page to the next without touching a server is to use localstorage.

Page one:

```
// set
localStorage.setItem('counter', counter);
```

Page two:

```
// retrieve
var counter = localStorage.getItem('counter');
```

This is supported in all browsers down to (and including) IE8

Answer (score -1):

FIRST SOLUTION:

U mean to say that u want to pass 'msg' variable to next page? ok if you are using form then this problem will be send using hidden input type "" to pass it in their value attribute using jquery like $('#passVar').val(msg). So when u submit the form this value will be get using post method.

SECOND SOLUTION

If you want to get this value in java script or jquery directly then you have to create a js file in which u create a java script global variable that will be used on both page in this case 'msg' will be global variable so what ever value will be assign in that variable u will be be easily get in next page.